# Simulate database structure

Tags: python, database, unix

I'm working on a script that is renaming most of the folders in my database. Material is so sensitive that I really don't like the idea of playing around with the script in the original database. I would love the idea of copy the structure only and test the script with the simulated structure.

Got this idea after a bad night of sleep, is this even doable?:)

Working with python in unix

Comment: What kind of 'database' do you use that has 'folders'?

Comment: This is a standard tree-structure, so database as a word might be somewhat misleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will duplicate structure of `a` to `b`.

```
import os

def dup_structure(src, dst):
    os.makedirs(dst)
    for p, ds, fs in os.walk(src):
        for dn in ds:
            dp = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(p, dn), src)
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(dst, dp))
        #for fn in fs:
        #    fp = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(p, fn), src)
        #    with open(os.path.join(dst, fp), 'wb'): pass

dup_structure('a', 'b')
```

- Ensure directory `b` is not exist before run.
- This code does **not** duplicate files. If you want duplicate files, uncomment commented lines.

---

**When you rename directories, you should traverse from bottom up to top directory.**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do this bit of shell script as part of the setup for the tests for your folder restructing program

```
cd /mytest/; find /folder/with/database -type d -print0 | xargs -0 mkdir -p
```

How it works:
chdir to the target you want the copy of the empty folders to go

The `find` command works with an absolute path to the "live" database

`type d` is directories only

`print0` means that it is safe to deal with names that contain spaces

`xargs` executes the command given with each of the parameters that are fed in at stdin

The -p parameter to mkdir isn't strictly needed but creates non existent folders above the target

If this was my project I would do this everytime I ran a automated test suite

Answer (score 0):

You could do it even with standard unix utilities without programming. Just create a tar archive of the directory structure and expand it wherever and as often you want (copy the structure of a to b):

```
cd a
find . -type d | xargs tar --no-recursion -r -f ../a.tar
cd ..
mkdir b
cd b
tar xf ../a.tar
```

Comment: I like the idea of making a tarball of the structure